# It seems to me that quasi-coherent sheaf is a sheaf of sheaves.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, sheaf-theory, quasicoherent-sheaves

In [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ringed_space), I was looking for the definition of quasi-coherent sheaf. However I got confused.

> It seems to me that quasi-coherent sheaf is a sheaf of sheaves.

Though, indeed, it says quasi-coherent sheaves are subcategory of $\mathcal{O}_X$-modules,  where $\mathcal{O}_X$-modules are defined as follows:

Let $X$ be a topological space and consider a locally ringed space $(X, \mathcal{O}_X)$. Then the wikipedia defines $\mathcal{O}_X$-modules to be a sheaf $F$ such that $F(U)$ is a module over the ring $\mathcal{O}_X(U)$ for every open set $U$ in $X$. Thats each $\mathcal{O}_X$-module is a sheaf $F$.

Next, the last para of wikipedia says, **a sheaf of $\mathcal{O}_X$-modules** (which itself a sheaf $F$) is quasi-coherent if it is, locally, isomorphic to the cokernel of the map between free $\mathcal{O}_X$-modules. Thus it seems to me that quasi-coherent sheaf is a sheaf of sheaves.

Can someone explain it please ?

Thanks

Comment: I don't really see where you are getting the sheaf of sheaves idea. A quasi-coherent sheaf is just a sheaf of abelian groups with particular properties.

Comment: It's not clear why anything you've written should lead to your quoted statement about a sheaf of sheaves. $\mathcal{O}_X$-modules are sheaves of modules.

Comment: @KReiser, see the bold words in the last para. This confused me. As you said $\mathcal{O}_X$-modules$:=$sheaves of modules, while from the bold words a quasi-coherent sheaf is a sheaf of $\mathcal{O}_X$-modules. Thus it says a quasi-coherent sheaf  is a sheaf of  $sheaves \ of \ \mathcal{O}_X$-$modules$. Can you please explain ?

Comment: This is just a very slightly different way to say the same thing from two different authors: potayto/pohtato. Don't worry about it.

Comment: @KReiser, thanks a lot for clarification